# How to create eshop for product hiring counting price per day

Tags: commerce

Currently I'm working on specific project which is product hiring and price per day depends on hiring interval. It means 2 days hiring for certain product the per day price differs from 5 days hiring. Also in this case instead of product quantity I'm using days. My question is how can I organize above mentioned structure using commerce?

Comment: I havent used Commerce much. But I understand it can use Rules for prices. It sounds like via Cron you want a daily rule to adjust your product prices.

Comment: Each product has price table, for example 1 - 2 days hiring price per days is x$, 3 - 5 days hiring - y$ and etc. And meanwhile, how can I develop n days hiring with order and line items?

Comment: Oh perhaps look at https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [Commerce Price Table](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_table) module which supports the following output for a table of prices/quantity:

[image: Price Table Options for Commerce]

> contrib project that allows to have a secondary price field that
>   considers the quantity for displaying and using the prices. It also
>   provides a field formatter to display the price/quantity values as a
>   table.